# Validar Textbox

Tags: c#

Necesito validar unos `textbox` en `C#` para que se ingresen solamente *números enteros*, con una cantidad exacta de dígitos, es decir que pueda ingresar cifras de *5 números* y no mayor a esta cantidad de caracteres.

¿Cómo podría hacer dicha validación?

Comment: ¿Es WinForms? ¿Tienes algún código que puedas compartir para dar un poco de contexto a la pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

Puede hacerlo usando otro control llamado "MaskedTextBox".

Este link le dara una buena idea de como usarlo: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1534/Masked-C-TextBox-Control

Answer (score 1):

Crea un metodo que reciba como parametro un textbox, de la siguiente manera

```
    public boolean validatxtLongitud(TextBox txttoValidate)
        {
try
{
         if(txttoValidate.Text().Lengh=5 && (int)txttovalidate.text()!=0)
          {
           return true;
          }
          else
          {
           return false;
          }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
throw e;
return false;
}
        }
```

Y donde lo uses realiza esto

```
if(validatxtLongitud(txtinput))
{
// haz algo
}
else
{
//haz otra cosa
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de los eventos, es bastante practico y considero que te ahorra mucho código.
El evento es `KeyPress`

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar)) //Comparas si la tecla presionada corresponde a un signo de puntuacion
        {
            e.Handled = true; //Si coincide se controla el evento, es decir, no se escribe el caracter
        }
        if (Char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar)) //Comparas si la tecla presionada corresponde a un simbolo
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar)) //Comparas si la tecla presionada corresponde a una letra
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

El código anterior sirve para sustituir las validaciones que se hacen comparando el contenido del `TextBox`, ya que solo se podran escribir numeros.

Y en cuanto a la longitud del `TextBox` hay dos maneras, una es visualmente modificando la propiedad `MaxLength` y asignandole el valor deseado, en tu caso 5.

O la otra es mediante código:

```
textBox1.MaxLength = 5; //Si es en WF puedes hacer la declaracion en el metodo Form_Load
```

Si te sirvió no olvides marcarla!

Answer (score 0):

A mi parecer la manera mas eficiente seía mediante una expresión regular, a continuación te dejo un ejemplo

```
        if(Regex.IsMatch(txtbox, @"^\d{5}$")){

         //EN CASO CORRECTO

        }else{

       //EN CASO DE ERROR

       }
```